# How to load the data within the viewset class automatically on the server?

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework

I had the backend Django project running on EC2, Ubuntu18.04, nginx. Basically, when I test the project locally by running 'python manage.py runserver', i can see the matrix i want to generate loaded before the server is ready to go. However, after i deployed it on the server, it gave back the error that the views doesn't have the attribute called 'matrix'.

I tried locally, and i can see my prints so that it truly generate the matrix. However, i cannot debug the project as the same way i did locally as i run the project automatically by setting up the .conf file.

```
module 'test.views' has no attribute 'matrix'

class CreateMatrixViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MatrixSerializer
    queryset = Matrix.objects.all()

    print("start creating ls_frame")
    global ls_frame
    ls_frame = read_frame(queryset)
    print("end creating ls_frame")
    print("start creating matrix")
    global matrix
    matrix = generateMatrix(ls_frame)
    print("end creating matrix")
    http_method_names = ['post']

    def create(self, request):
        ...
```

I assume that when running on the server, it won't do the initial loading. So if i want to generate something before i make the server ready, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

This code has many many problems, and I can't see how it can have worked locally. To mark a variable as global you need to actually define it first at module level. But you should *never, ever* be using global variables in a multi-user environment like Django; and certainly not as class attributes, that makes no sense at all.

The root of your problem is trying to run code at class level anyway. Again, that makes no sense. I don't understand why you are trying to run `read_frame` and `generateMatrix` there; you should run them inside a method (I can't tell you what method, as I have no idea what you are trying to do with the results.)

Comment: I am using Django rest framework and the reason i am running the read_frame and generateMatrix is because it takes more than 30 seconds every time i do the serarch function to generate the matrix. I don't want  my end users to wait every time they search sth. So i generate it globally at the very beginning to reduce waiting time.

Comment: So, either do it at class level and store the results as class attributes, or do it at module level and store the results there (where they will automatically be global). Don't try and mix the two. But you must only do this if it's absolutely certain that they don't store per user data.